# Slowly calm down a speedometer

Tags: c#, timer, keyevent

I'm working on a simulator of car driving. The idea is simple: at the moment you just press space bar and while its pressed the speed keeps growing. Once you released the space key the speed should slowly go down but instead it goes down at the right moment.
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH0Cp.png)

So is there a way I can make my speedbar go down slowly and in a smooth way?

Here's gif demonstration: 
https://psv4.vk.me/c810336/u26848512/docs/44c13660f362/gif.gif?extra=4MqKvdhJzi7zl0QBLC6Vw2sUPznozeuDjmPcsMRJGRmN3VaN-Oa7Tjp_0nZrlDgjAfDGVuKO7bhwu-363yx_XGYVh8FoGGhXHzBoROEQjhuB-QsJghVq1f3s
I tried to do it with KeyUp even but it works just at the right moment. I also tried Timer but same story.

Here's my code:

```
        float angle = -35.0f;
    Image img;

    public MPh()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.pictureBox1.Parent = image;
        this.pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new Point(402, 100);

        img = new Bitmap("../../resources/speed.png");
        pictureBox1.Image = Utilities.RotateImage(img, angle);

        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void MPh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            if (angle < 215.0f)
                angle += 1.0f;

            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)img.Clone();

            Image oldImage = pictureBox1.Image;

            pictureBox1.Image = Utilities.RotateImage(img, angle);

            if (oldImage != null)
            {
                oldImage.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    private void test()
    {

        angle -= 1.0f;

        pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)img.Clone();

        Image oldImage = pictureBox1.Image;

        pictureBox1.Image = Utilities.RotateImage(img, angle);

        if (oldImage != null)
        {
            oldImage.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void MPh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (angle > -35.0f)
            test();
    }
```

Comment: What is the interval set to for your timer?

Comment: @Sean it's 100. I tried to change it but it just slows the programme and then same fast returns to origin.